# Are there other pre-trained time series transformers than TimeGPT?

Tags: time-series, transformer

I am looking for pre-trained transformers trained on time-series data to use for transfer learning (for forecasting).

I found TimeGPT, and it does claim in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.03589.pdf) to be the first foundation model. However, that is a claim I am skeptical of; The claim in the abstract is very broad.

Are there any others?